# List index out of range syntax error

Tags: python, list, pygame, index-error

I am creating a 2D fighting via pygame. An error that occurred when I first started coding the game has crept back up on the same line of code from before and I managed to fix it, but this time I am not to sure how to resolve a solution.

```
class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 300
        self.y_change = 0
        self.ani_speed_init = 8
        self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
        self.ani_stand =glob.glob("characters\\Naruto\\Standing\\naruto_s*.png")
        self.ani_stand.sort()
        self.moving = True
        self.ani_pos=0
        self.ani_max = len(self.ani_stand)-1
```

The next line of code is where the index out of range error is occurring. This is located in the `player1` class in the `__init__` subroutine. This line of code loads an image in position 0 of the list.

```
self.img_stand = pygame.image.load(self.ani_stand[0])
self.ani_walk = glob.glob("characters\\Naruto\\Walk\\naruto_w*.png")
self.ani_walk.sort()
self.ani_pos=0
self.ani_max_walk = len(self.ani_walk)-1
```

If new frames are added, finds out how many frames there are and when it hits the maximum ammount loops back to Zero in the array of sprites.

```
self.img_walk = pygame.image.load(self.ani_walk[0])
self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani_stand[0])
self.jumping = False
self.velocity_index = 0
self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
self.count = 0
self.update(0)
```

This is the update function in the player 1 class. This section of code is where I previously managed to amend the error the first time.

```
def update(self,pos):
    if pos != 0: 
        self.ani_speed-=1
        self.x+=pos

        if self.ani_speed == 0:
            self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani_walk[self.ani_pos])
            self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
            if self.ani_pos == self.ani_max_walk:
                self.ani_pos = 0
            else:
                self.ani_pos += 1
```

This `else` block, situated in the `update` function, was the specific section of code used to resolve a solution but i cant seem to think of anymore logical solutions to fix the error.

```
else:
    self.ani_speed-=1
    if self.moving: 
        self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
        if self.count==8:
            if self.ani_pos >= self.ani_max:
                self.ani_pos = 1
            else:
                self.ani_pos+=1
        elif self.ani_pos>3:
            self.ani_pos=1

        self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani_stand[self.ani_pos-1])
gameDisplay.blit(self.img,(self.x,self.y))
```

Comment: Full code can be viewed at : https://hastebin.com/isivuxozeb.rb

Comment: Does that path actually exist on your system?

Comment: It's better if you can show us *less* code rather than *more*. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem with all extraneous code removed. The MCVE doesn't need to do anything meaningful; it just needs to have the same problem.

Comment: @internet_user  the path is correct

Comment: is there any advice or solutions you could put forward about this block of code ive added though? @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't have to do anything with Pygame. Your call to `glob`

```
glob.glob("characters\\Naruto\\Standing\\naruto_s*.png")
```

returns an empty array. Check what directory your script is executed in and whether the files at the specified path actually exist.

Comment: Yep checked if the path was edited or changed but it all correct

Comment: You should check within the code itself. Where do you run the interpreter from? How do you start the code? Try placing a debug breakpoint at the glob call and trying to figure out which actual directory it's trying to read.

Comment: I am familiar with a interpreter but not to sure where to locate the point at which it is ran. Also when mentioning debug breakpoint , do you mean adding in print statements to asses which directory its trying to read?

Comment: I cant seem to figure out why its suddenly returning a empty array when being called, everything was working fine yesterday and nothing has been edited since.

Comment: I mean actual debug breakpoint, either in an IDE if you use one, or try either using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before the `glob` statement, or just run `glob.glob("characters\\Naruto\\Walk\\naruto_w*.png")` from the interpreter and examine its output.

Comment: Okay , i am not familiar with debug breakpoint as i am only an A level student and it has never been mentioned before by my teacher. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/breakpoints.html.
This post on PyCharm's website explains what breakpoints are and how to use them in PyCharm (seemingly the most popular Python IDE). **Note:** You do not *need an IDE to successfully debug your program. IDEs just make it easier*.